# Navigating an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a problem on my implementation of QM Method on java.

I am having a problem with navigating a 2D ArrayList. My goal in the code is by having the first element of ArrayList in being the address and each time another binary is paired up, i will find that address and add the address of the paired binary.

Is there any way to use the indexOf Function in finding the index of the first element in a 2D Array?

Example.
My 2D ArrayList named table is
[4][3][7];[7][4];[8][3];[9];

I want to add int 5 to the the line where [4] is. so my code goes table.get(table.indexOf(4)).add(5) but it keeps saying that the index is -1. Please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

So consider...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

// populate list

Integer index = myList.indexOf(4);

// index is -1 because 4 is not of type: ArrayList<Integer>
```

If you need to add values to an ArrayList based on an integer index, I would consider switching to a different container type such as:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>
```

The alternative is not using indexOf ... but instead write your own function to loop through 0 to myList.size() looking for myList.get(loopIndex).get(0) = address to be found, then returning the outer ArrayList index where it was found